# Angular 2 remove an object

Tags: angular

I have the following method I use to delete a comment, using an API call:

```
deleteComment(comment) {
      //My attack
        let body = JSON.stringify({
                commentID: comment.id
        });

        comment = null;

    this.http.request('deleteComment',
    { body:body, method:'POST' })
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log("COMMENT DELETED");
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.text());
        }
      );
  }
```

Although I set the comment to `null` I still see the comment in my comments list. Is it possible to remove it from the page withouot making another API call to refresh the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just set the local variable to `null`. As soon as `deleteComment()` is completed the effect is void.

Perhaps you mean

```
this.comments.splice(this.comments.indexOf(comment), 1);
```

but it's unclear what you mean with "my comments list"

Comment: I have `comments` variable which contains a list of `comment` object. Once a selected `comment` is deleted, I want to remove it from `comments` object list. `comment` is an object from that list.

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to remove the element from the array.

Comment: I should have known better than to compete with you, Gunter :)

Comment: Sorry, @jhhoff02 I know I'm quite annoying ;-) Just don't give up. Answering questions is the best training to get better.

Answer (score 0):

I would try filtering out null comments upon successful comment deletion. Have not tested, but would look something like:

```
this.http.request('deleteComment',
{ body:body, method:'POST' })
  .map((res:Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => {
        this.comments.filter(c => c !== null)
        console.log("COMMENT DELETED");
    },
```

assuming you're keeping an array of comments to iterate in the comment section.

Comment: I do have an array of comments named comments stored as `this.comments` but this solution doesn't work, the comment is still shown upon deleting

Comment: Could you post an example of what your `comments` array looks like with data in it?